# How to drop variables in statistical classification analysis?

Tags: classification, multivariate-analysis

Given a set of data with variables and a training set, we can proceed classification analysis using Mahalanobis distance etc.(discriminant methods)

But how do we know whether all these given variables are essential in classification?

For example, when we are given data set:

```
Number Math P.E. History
001    100  80   60
002    99   81   65
003    40   82   99
004    30   76   100
```

It can be deduced that 001 and 002 are math persons while 003 and 004 are history person. But when we proceed classification analysis, the P.E. score is non-related. We can drop the column of P.E. and just yield the same classification result.

My question is: how can we drop these unrelated variables in a data set? This is important because dropping such variables in a big data set greatly reduce the work of classifying.

I asked some of my tutors. One of them suggested this may be resolved by proceeding a principal component analysis before classification. But I pointed out that principal component analysis may assume a latent linear model. He agreed with that.

Is there any resolution for this problem?

Comment: This is a specific instance of feature selection, also called variable selection. Wikipedia has [an overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection).

Comment: @Dougal Thank you for your editing and link, I will have a good look into it!